# Line x and y n-intercept point / C++

Tags: c++, line, point, intercept

Can someone please help me. I understand the equation of a line and how to solve for the zero intercept on paper, but I have trouble converting it to code. More specifically, I need to calculate the point at which a line intercepts any given X or Y coordinate with two different functions...

```
double CalcLineYIntercept(LINE *line, double yintercept) { }
double CalcLineXIntercept(LINE *line, double xintercept) { }
```

So, `CalcLineYIntercept` would return the X coordinate of the point where the line intercepts `yintercept` (not necessarily zero). I have trouble converting algebraic equations to code (and yes I understand that C++ is an algebraic language, but the code itself does not simply and isolate variables). Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Thank you very much

Comment: We require the declaration of `LINE` to answer this. Maybe also write down the formula you want to implement.

Comment: LINE is simple a coordinate of two points, doubles, x1, y1, x2, y2. y=mx+b is the equation of a line, and y2 - y1 / x2 - x1 is the slope (m), and b is the offset, but I'm not sure how to work b into the equation here, or how to write that into code. I need the n-intercept point (the intercept point for any given coordinate, not just zero)

Comment: @user491232: Please edit your question and add the information you provided in you comment.

Comment: So you want to pass an x=(X) (or y=(Y)) and find where your line hits the adjusted axis?

Answer (score 4):

```
double CalcLineYIntercept(LINE *line, double yintercept) 
{ 
    dx = line->x2 - line->x1;
    dy = line->y2 - line->y1;

    deltay = yintercept - line->y2;
    if (dy != 0) { 
        //dy very close to 0 will be numerically unstable, account for that
        intercept = line->x2 + (dx/dy) * deltay;
    }
    else {
        //line is parrallel to x-axis, will never reach yintercept
        intercept = NaN;
    }
}
```

Reverse x and y to get the other function.

Comment: If this answered your question, perhaps you could accept this question as the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Subtract `yintercept` from the line's *y*-coordinates, then use the math you already know to solve for *x* when *y* = 0. Mutatis Mutandis for `xintercept`.